# Browser-Sync does not Sync HTML and CSS files at once

Tags: html, css, browser, synchronization

I have a HTML file named `index.html` and a CSS file named `style.css`in a directory named `CSS3 for everybody` like so.

`C:\Users\a\Desktop\Web-Design for everybody specialization\CSS3 for everybody`

I am trying to make Browser-Sync recognize that there is a .html and a .css file by running `browser-sync start --server 'CSS3 for everybody' --files 'CSS3 for everybody'` but nothing happens. It says "Connected to Browser Sync" and the page remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the index.html file u should specify to load the style.css file using the import rule like so

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
@import "style.css";
</style>
```

Comment: The file name was wrong in the `<link>` tag. Instead of `style.css` it was something else!! I have also tried your solution and it worked. Thank You very much for taking some time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Browser-Sync was confused due to incorrect file name in the `<link>` tag.

Earlier it was `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">`

After changing it to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` CSS started getting injected.